# JW Player 7 pause on precise time

Tags: youtube, jwplayer, jwplayer7

I'm playing around with YouTube embed video. I want the player to pause on third second. Code below:

```
playerInstance.on('time', function(x) {
    if (x.position === 3){
        playerInstance.pause();
    }
});
```

But it dosen't work everytime. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. It's totally random. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the media type being played and other events hooked to the JW player instance, the "onTime" event is fired multiple times a second, and is reported to numerous decimal places.

It is therefore very unlikely that the "position" will ever be exactly 3 (which is what you are effectively saying with the following: '==' & '===').

It would be more robust to use '>=':

```
playerInstance.on('time', function(x) {
    if (x.position >= 3){
        playerInstance.pause();
    }
});
```

However, this as-is would mean the player would not be able to play beyond 3 seconds, so depending on your requirements, you may also need to include additional logic to cater for the following:

- continuing to play after the pause point
- what to do if the user seeks beyond 3 seconds
- seeking back and then reaching the pause point a second time
- etc...

Probably a better solution would be to convert the "position" to an integer value and do a direct comparison. That means you wouldn't need logic to handle progressing past the pause point. You would however need logic to ensure it was only paused once at the pause point. The following caters for this:

```
playerInstance.on('time', function(x){
    if(parseInt(x.position,10)===3){
        if(!playerInstance["pauseOnce"]){
            playerInstance["pauseOnce"]=true;
            playerInstance.pause();
        }
    }else{
        playerInstance["pauseOnce"]=false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I think that would be a good solution. I have been trying with >= but haven't thought about include additional logic. I thought exact position would do the trick. But its works random.

Comment: Thinking about this further, I've provided an update with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into issues before when throwing my jwplayer object into a variable. I don't have an explanation, but I would venture that you might have better luck if you just keep using the jwplayer(); call explicitly. Hopefully that gives you more consistent results. Also maybe try with '==' instead of '==='. Can you show us how you're declaring playerInstance?

Answer (score 0):

I used recommended declaration - [JW Player website Api](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1413074-javascript-api-quick-start)

"We encourage developers to stop using the jwplayer() syntax, and instead keep a reference to the player instance. Based on how JW Player 7 is engineered, this will actually save a few ms of time during player setup."

`var playerInstance = jwplayer('container');
//jwplayer('container').pause(); // BAD! :(
playerInstance.pause(); // Good :)`

I just tested out your solution with just jwplayer() declaration also with '==' & '==='. But it still dosen't work.

I prepared a fiddle for You with our 2 declaration.

http://jsfiddle.net/slk500/rftbtzpr/

Thanks for your help!